# Azure Service Bus issue

Tags: azure, servicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I'm working on a project where we would like to use ServiceBus like a classical queue, for messaging. Very often I see messages in queue that I can't get. These messages are active (not dead letters). I don't receive any exceptions, it waits for timeout and then message is null without any issues. I've already checked size of messages but all are less then 1.5 KB.

```
try
...
QueueClient _queueClient = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(Properties.Settings.Default.ServiseBusConnectionString, Properties.Settings.Default.StatQueueName);

var count = 1000;

for (var i = 1; i <= count; i++)
{
 var message = _queueClient.Receive();
 //timeout 
 if (message == null)
 {
  //message is null :(
  continue;
 }
}
...
catch
```

Comment: Have you tried using the Azure ServiceBus explorer to retrieve the messages?  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/paolos/archive/2014/12/04/service-bus-explorer-2-5-now-available.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Read [How to receive messages from a queue](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-queues/) and make sure you use `_queueClient.Complete()` or `_queueClient.Abandon()` to finish with each message.

Comment: Yes, I do complete or abandon, I showed just part of code. If you don't do it in 30 sec timeout, message will be marked as dead-letter.

Comment: AFAIK default TTL in a queue is quite infinite (using Visual Studio you can see 10675199.02:48:05.4775807 as value in DefaultMessageTimeToLive). Can you check this value in your queue ?